# how to read multiple binary files in C++ program without the use of boost library

Tags: c++, file, boost

I have variable numbers of binary files (over 100). Each file is huge but has exactly the same numbers of float (e.g., 1E8). Some function/operation will be applied to the float numbers with the same subscript among files, for example, the 10th number in each file.

Since the total size of files are large, so it is inefficient to firstly read all files into the memory and then do the operation. Instead, I want to do this in a on-line manner.

```
vector<string> file (nfiles, file_prefix);
vector<shared_ptr<ifstream> > in;
for(int g = 0; g < nfile; ++g){
  ostringstream fid;
  fid << file_id[g];
  file[g] = file[g] + fid.str() + string(".bin");

  in.push_back(make_shared<ifstream> (file[g].c_str())); //how to specify ios::binary??
}

vector<float> s(nfiles);
for(int i = 0; i < nlines; ++i){
  for(int g = 0; g < nfiles; ++g){
    in[g].read((char*) s[g], sizeof(float));
  }
  // do something with s
}
```

The code above doesn't work since I don't know how to specify ios::binary when creating the stream for each file. It is used to show what I want. Also, it depends on boost library which is not allowed to be used in my project. I want to learn a solution without the use of boost.

**Edit:** according to comments in this thread, I learnt that boost is not actually required even if I use `make_shared`. I still don't understand why I got an error `no matching function for call to 'make_shared'` in the line `in.push_back(...)`

**Edit:** The compiling error is due to a typo in my code. So all my questions in this thread are resolved.

Comment: Do you mean it depends on boost, because of the `shared_ptr`? This is part of the current standard meanwhile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I meant make_shared.

Comment: @HanZhang see std::make_shared in <memory>

Comment: @helsinki would you please give more specific information? I tried including <memory> but got the same error: no matching function for call to 'make_shared'. I compile it under mac, but also want it work on unix-like OS. Any reference about using make_shared and stream together is great

Comment: @HanZhang I guess you are using clang++, since `std::make_shared` ships with c++11, give it a try by adding `--std=c++11` to clang++ params

Comment: Rolled back your last edit, since it invalidated your question and made it useless for future research. If an answer solved your question mark it as accepted, but don't fix your code in question.

Comment: Just post an answer, if you think it useful, mark it accepted to end this question, and please follow what @πάντα ῥεῖ said above.

Comment: The best part: you don't even need `shared_ptr` nor `make_shared` to make this work. I'm tempted to say "copy & paste programming". Hard to make the judgement from a distance, I know, but I'd be alerted if it were my team member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your platform is osx, and `std::make_shared` ships with c++11, give it a try by adding `--std=c++11` to clang++ params.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::make_shared<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) forwards its arguments to appropriate constructors.

```
  gin.push_back(std::make_shared<ifstream> (gene_out[g].c_str(), std::ios::binary));
```

The above will forward `gene_out[g].c_str()` and `std::ios::binary` to the [`std::ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/) initialization constructor.

```
explicit ifstream (const char* filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);
```